# ¿Como validar Fecha?

Tags: java, java-ee

Buen dia,

Lo siguiente es, tengo una clase Fecha que maneja dia, mes, año, como entero cada una y en tal clase un metodo que es validarFecha.
La cuestion es que la fecha se ingresa por teclado en el metodo main y la recibe una clase X que tiene con un atributos variables de tipo Fecha, como hago funcionar el metodo validarFecha de la clase Fecha.

```
public class Fecha {
    private int anio;
    private int dia;
    private int mes;

    public Fecha() {
    }

    public Fecha(int anio, int dia, int mes){
        setAnio(anio);
        setDia(dia);
        setMes(mes);
    }

    public int getAnio(){
        return anio;
    }

    public int getDia(){
        return dia;
    }


    public int getMes(){
        return mes;
    }

    public void setAnio(int anio){
        this.anio=anio;
    }

    public void setDia(int dia){
        this.dia=dia;
    }

    public void setMes(int mes){
        this.mes=mes;
    }

    public boolean validadFecha(){
        boolean validoFecha=false;

        if (dia<1 || dia>31) {
            validoFecha=true;
        }

        if (mes<1 || mes>12) {
            validoFecha=true;
        }

        if (mes==2 && dia==29 && anio % 400 == 0 || (anio % 4 == 0 && anio % 100 != 0) ) {
            validoFecha=true;
            }



        return validoFecha;
        }
}
```

Comment: Usa Date y Calendar

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto [tour] y de paso conseguir su primera medalla, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando [ask] para tener mas posibilidades de recibir una respuesta adecuada

Comment: El problema es que la clase Fecha tiene variables de tipo entero "dia, mes, año" no hay la virtud de utilizar Date

Comment: Ayuda que pongas tu código para ver cuánto tienes ya y poder construir sobre eso, no sabemos de dónde proviene tu problema porque no conocemos la estructura de 'validarFecha'.

Comment: Deberías poner el código de lo que estás intentando y el formato de fecha que quieres usar, como por ejemplo `10 de Enero de 2015` o `10/01/2015` o `2015-01-10`

Comment: `public class Fecha {
 private int anio;
 private int dia;
 private int mes;`  con sus respectivos setter y getter, como ven cada uno se maneja por enteros

Comment: Deberías dar a [edit] y añadir el código de tu main en la pregunta

Comment: La respuesta de @Juanant es perfectamente válida en tu situación, la clave está en 'SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  formatoFecha.parse(this.dia + "/" + this.mes + "/" + this.anno);'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo que en la clase Main (Principal) estás pidiendo al usuario que introduzca la fecha en tres pasos (dia, mes y año) y que estás usando un "constructor" en la clase Fecha para iniciar las variables `dia`, `mes` y `anio`, deberías hacer esto...

En la clase Main, después de pedir la fecha, llama a la clase `Fecha` y al método `validarFecha()`

```
boolean correcto = false;

Fecha fecha = new Fecha(dia, mes, anio);

correcto = fecha.validarFecha();

if (correcto == true) {
    System.out.println("La fecha es correcta");
} else {
    System.out.println("La fecha es incorrecta");
}
```

Si quieres mejorar tu código deberías usar esto en tu clase `Fecha`:

```
public boolean validarFecha() {
    boolean correcto = false;

    try {
        //Formato de fecha (día/mes/año)
        SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        formatoFecha.setLenient(false);
        //Comprobación de la fecha
        formatoFecha.parse(this.dia + "/" + this.mes + "/" + this.anio);
        correcto = true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //Si la fecha no es correcta, pasará por aquí
        correcto = false;
    }

    return correcto;
}
```

Prueba a ver

Comment: Creo que este ejemplo es de lo mas completo y se ajusta perfectamente a tu necesidad. Solo aclarar que deberías de intentar utilizar Calendar siempre que hablemos de tratamientos de fechas, para este caso básico no es necesario pero solo por tenerlo presente.

Comment: Si nos ponemos quisquillosos, debería usar `DateTimeFormatter` y `LocalDate`, desde Java 8 existe el paquete `java.time` y usar Date o SimpleDateFormat no es lo más aconsejable

Comment: @Juanant vaya solucion me ha servido, muchas gracias, buen dia.

Answer (score 2):

Lo fácil es intentar convertir a `LocalDate` y capturar la excepción.
Una expresión regular te permitiría validar la corrección de los campos, pero no podría verificar el 29 de Febrero.

Un ejemplo

```
    private boolean esFechaValida(int anio, int dia, int mes){
        boolean esFechaValida = true;
        try{
            LocalDate.of(anio, mes, dia);
        }catch(DateTimeException e) {
            esFechaValida = false;
        }
        return esFechaValida;
    }
```

Comment: Sencillo y usando `java.time`, que hoy día es lo aconsejable, buena respuesta