# Validar fecha correcta en aplicacion android

Tags: java, android

Como puedo validar que el dispositivo que ejecuta mi aplicacion esté con la fecha correcta, es decir, en caso que el usuario cambie su configuracion con otra fecha mi aplicacion muestre el mensaje "fecha incorrecta".

**Edit**

Tengo este codigo como base:

```
SimpleDateFormat ISO_8601_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        ISO_8601_FORMAT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String date = ISO_8601_FORMAT.format(new Date());
        System.out.println("date:" + date);
```

e imprime en consola

> I/System.out: date:20191003

Siendo que la fecha actual es 20191004, contra que comparo mi variable `date`, algun servicio de internet o algo?

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, gracias

Comment: Aquí hay un [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174706/como-validar-fecha) que te puede ser útil.

Comment: Hola Wilmer, eres usuario que lleva algo de tiempo en el sitio, agrega lo que has intentado y modifica tu pregunta en base a [ask], saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys, gracias por responder, he modificado mi pregunta, no se si ya se entiende?

Comment: @Wilmer esa fecha incorrecta se obtiene en un emulador o dispositivo real, este tiene conexión a internet?

Comment: @Jorgesys, la fecha se obtiene en un emulador con conexion a internet. La finalidad de todo esto es para que los usuarios no hagan alguna especie de 'trampa' cambiando la fecha de su terminal, ya que mi app da una recompensa diaria. No se como plantear la solucion.

Comment: puedes usar una [api externa](http://worldtimeapi.org/) para validar la hora o utilizar la hora de tu servidor y no la de la aplicacion local.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que uses la palabra "validar", significa que existe algun lugar que guarda las reglas para hacer esa validación.

Si algun dispositivo dice que la fecha actual es 1/1/1970, a quien le confias que eso sea correcto o incorrecto? A el dispositivo de a lado? a algun servidor local en la oficina? a la universidad local?

Para esto existe NTP: Network Time Protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol

Existen servidores alrededor del mundo en los que "confiamos" que tienen la información exacta de "cuando" es "ahora". Esto tambien significa que vas a necesitar internet.

Al final del día, tienes que "confiar" en que tu dispositivo tiene la hora correcta. Android YA tiene un sistema para hacer su mejor esfuerzo posible para manterner la deficinicón de "ahora " correcta. NO es el trabajo de una aplicacion mantener esta sincronización por lo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es *confiar* en que android hizo su mejor esfuerzo para obtener la fecha/hora correcta y que TU no puedes hacer un mejor trabajo que el dispositivo para ello.

Comment: Y confiando en que android ya hizo bien su trabajo, el usuario se cambia la hora manualmente a dentro de una semana y el juego que tanto trabajo te ha costado hacer le regala una semana de progreso en IDLE... sinceramente, nunca se debe *confiar* en algo que puede manipular un usuario, porque nunca jamás se debe tomar algún dato de un usuario como correcto sin validarlo tú en backend... a los usuarios les gusta demasiado toquetear donde no deben ;)